# VNC connection not displaying correctly

Tags: graphics, remote

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and trying to vnc to a netbook running Ubuntu 32 bit 14.04. Whenever I connect I just get a grey image of a screen and my mouse appears as a black x (can't attach images right now:() is this a colours issue? If so does anyone know how I go about changing it? I am using tightvncserver and viewer.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you create a suitable ~/.vnc/xstartup file on the netbook? otherwise you will just get a minimal X session with a plain gray root window

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because the VNC session you are using is unable to load the currently selected display manager.
You can resolve this by changing your xstartup file to use an alternative display manager which does not require graphics acceleration.
There are instructions on how to configure this available [Here](https://support.realvnc.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/345)